# Object.values return JS array without '[ ]'. : how to we know if the value was an array or not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In my code, I have two JSON files. I go through each entry of the first one and compare its values with the second one. And depending of the result, I create a 3rd JSON file out of this, the 3rd one is a kind of "merged" result of the two first files.

To compare them. I use Object.values function to get the values of the current entry. When i'm encountering a simple string or integer value it does something like this :

```
var json = '{ "key":"Team" }';
json = JSON.parse(json);
var value = Object.values(json)[0];  //Return: Team
```

Which is a good output. But when i'm on an Array. It does something like this :

```
var json = `{ "key":"Team" , "default value":["Team Red","Team Blue"] }`;
json = JSON.parse(json);
var key = Object.values(json)[0];
var defaultvalue = Object.values(json)[1];
console.log(key + " --- " + defaultvalue); //Return : Team --- Team Red, Team Blue
```

The problem with that output is that if I want to make a 3rd JSON file out of this. the new file will be {"default value": "Team Red, Team Blue"} instead of {"default value" : ["Team Red", "Team Blue"]}

Do you know a way of knowing if the current value is a JSON array so I can have an array in my 3rd file instead of a simple string ? Thank you for your help :)

**EDIT**

Thank to your responses, I now know the difference between the stringified version of a console.log and the "parsed" one depending with we add other strings or not to the console.log call.

But that doesn't help me much. Because like I said. I'm constructing a 3rd JSON file out of this. So I still need to stringify my array. Is there a way to stringify an array like like `["Team Red", "Team Blue"]` and output this exact value as a string without loosing the `[ ]` or `"`   ?

I can still check if it is an array with `Array.isArray()` and then go through every entry of the array to reconstruct it with the same syntax. But is there a better way ?

Comment: But...`Object.values(json)[1];` will give you an *array*. The only reason you're seeing it as a string is because you are doing `" --- " + defaultvalue`.

Comment: `Array.isArray(json)` will tell you whether the object is an array. It is not a good idea at all to expect any particular property order to be returned from `Object.values()`. Your code should find the actual property name you want.

Comment: You're getting ahead of yourself. Don't worry, javascript knows that Object.values(json)[1] is an Array – what you're seeing is just how console.log deals with the array value

Comment: @MichaelBeeson nope, in this case OP is converting the array to a string when logging it to console. Usually consoles would still show you the array differently to a string.

Comment: Agree with @VLAZ . You would get a different result if you do `console.log(key, " --- ", defaultvalue)`

Comment: Oops, indeed you're right @VLAZ

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've edited my post with more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

`JSON.stringify` will stringify the array while keeping [ ] and " " like any JSON input.
From my example, it output ["Team Red", "Team Blue"] like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

As VLAZ and Pointy said in comments to your question, you should get an array in calling `Object.values(json)[1]` (although it is not recommended to do so not checking if an array contains such key)
You can make sure with `Array.isArray(json)` if it is an array or not (it returns boolean).

Answer (score 0):

'defaultvalue' variable is infact an array - 
when you log it with 'key' variable it is stringified 
No need to worry :)
 Although if you want to check it using  Array.isArray(json) if it is an array or not (which will return a boolean answer).

```js
var json = `{ "key":"Team" , "default value":["Team Red","Team Blue"] }`;
json = JSON.parse(json);
var key = Object.values(json)[0];
var defaultvalue = Object.values(json)[1];
console.log(key + " --- " + defaultvalue); //Return : Team --- Team Red, Team Blue
//But if console this -----
console.log(defaultvalue) // Returns  ["Team Red", "Team Blue"]
```

Comment: Okay, I understand now the different between the stringified version or a Console.log when we add other string value. But, since I put the output array inside a new string to make the 3rd file. My array will still be stringified, so it does not help much.. :(